Conditional 503 only for some ingresses configured in one central place
I need a maintenance mode that

when activated (via helm value or a configmap)
returns a 503
to specific routes (/api and others)
unless a preview header is set.

Because I don't want to change all ingress resources, I'm trying to configure that with *-snippets in the nginx configmap.
I was able to introduce a preview variable
http-snippet: |
    map $http_x_preview $preview_request {
      default 0;
      "true" 1; 
    }

So, when the heaeder x-preview is set to true, the variable will be set to 1.
Now, I need something like this to only response with a 502 when the location matches certain paths.
server-snippet: |
    if ($preview_request = 0) {
        location /api {
          return 502;
        }
    }


This snippet is not working since location is not allowed in an if. The other way around doesn't work either. I also tried lua snippets (e.g. init_by_lua_block) but I couldn't use that because nginx then complains about the block being already available.
Any ideas on how I could set this up centrally without modifying all ingress resources?

Http-snippet will add custom configuration to the http section of the nginx configuration. Try to use nginx map and rewrite, parameters inside the map block specify a mapping between source and resulting values.
http-snippets: |
map $http_x_preview $is_preview
{
“true” 1;
default 0;
}

Instead of using location, you can achieve the same behavior by using rewrite inside the server-snippet, and also define the location-snippet that handles the /preview-503 and return 503 status code.
